# Dedekind zeta functions as Mellin transforms

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, modular-forms

This is surely well known and I might even have seen it before:

The Riemann zeta function can be expressed as a Mellin transform:

$$\Gamma(s)\zeta(s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\frac{1}{e^x - 1}dx.$$

How does one express the Dedekind zeta function as a Mellin transform, particularly for totally real number fields or CM fields? I believe in these two cases, it comes from modular forms - which ones?

What happens (or is expected to happen) in the more general case of L-functions associated to the various characters on these fields?

Comment: Similar statements should be stated in Neukirchs "Algebraic Numbertheory".

Comment: Yes, there is. I believe the gamma function should be replaced with a higher dimensional analogue. The correct functions are certain theta functions...

Comment: Is Tate's thesis considered an answer?

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember my motivation for asking this question but I believe I was looking for some global (well known...) object whose Mellin transform is the dedekind zeta function. As far as I understand it, Tate's thesis is purely local, right?

Comment: Hm, depends on what you mean by local, and what you are looking for (what "well known" means). You can think of Riemann zeta as Mellin transform of theta function (if you use the "right" gamma factors at archimedean place). This viewpoint generalizes directly, but theta function now becomes "integral of theta function over idele class group", which may or may not be acceptable to you. Tate's thesis phrases this viewpoint in idelic language, but you could have phrased this as an integral of theta functions over ...

Comment: norm 1 elements in $(K \otimes \mathbb{R})^*$ mod units of $O_K$, if $K$ is a number field and $O_K$ is the integers. (For example, it's spelled out in https://www.mit.edu/~fengt/263C.pdf p.13, but this is likely what Hecke originally did anyway)

Comment: I see! That indeed seems to have been what I was asking. Thanks a lot!